# Receive data with jQuery POST ajax request and Laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm trying to use an old Laravel 3 code in my new Laravel 4 app.

When I send a ajax post request I can't receive the data.

View:

```
   request = $.ajax({
        url: "/clients/jsonbyname/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
                "name": "hi"
              }
    });

   request.done(function (res, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if (res.status = "ok"){     
        console.log(res);
       }
   }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/clients/jsonbyname', 'Clients@postJsonbyname');
```

Changed to: (update)

```
Route::post('/clients/jsonbyname', 'Clients@postJsonbyname');
```

Controller:

```
public function postJsonbyname(){
    return dd(Input::get('name'));
}
```

Old: I cannot received the "name" data and I received NULL.
Update: Console give me 404 error

This was working in Laravel 3 and I don't know what's wrong.

Thank you

Comment: If you hit the /clients/jsonbyname manually in the browser, what is the result?

Comment: POST request cannot works with the last slash in url. Changed `url: "/clients/jsonbyname/",` to url: `"/clients/jsonbyname",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route says its get, but you're posting it.  Change it to `Route::post(...)` or change your request from the client side to get:

```
type: "GET",
```

Comment: Ok, I chaged to `Route::post('/clients/jsonbyname', 'Clients@postJsonbyname');` and now console give me 404
:/

Comment: Is your `Clients` class in the root namespace?

Comment: I don't use namespaces. Whatever... with GET I can access

Comment: `url: "/clients/jsonbyname/",` makes a redirection.

Comment: `url: "/clients/jsonbyname",` is the solution

Answer (score 1):

You're making a 'POST' request in your ajax call, but you're expecting a GET request. Use a GET request.

```
   request = $.ajax({
        url: "/clients/jsonbyname/",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
                "name": "hi"
              }
    });

   request.done(function (res, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if (res.status = "ok"){     
        console.log(res);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a POST request to a GET route.